# Create new variable and datset (sum of columns)

Tags: r

I want to create a new data set with new variable (sum of each columns).

The original data set is like this:

```
A B C D E F
0 1 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 0
```

So I want to get a new data set with new variable (calculate each sum of columns)  The final dataset should like this:

```
 Sum
A  1
B  1
C  2
D  2
E  2
F  2
```

In the new data set, A -F can be a categorical level in new dataset.
I can use `colSums(df)` to get each number,but I want to get new variable with these numbers.

Comment: Just create a `data.frame(Sum = colSums(df))`

Comment: @akrun thx! it works.